# Kotlin: Unresolved reference: java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

I surprised, because i was able to checkout and run a Kotlin project from Github without this error, and now  get get this Java-Error

[image: Unresolved reference: java]

I using

- kotlinc-jvm 1.3.60 (JRE 11.0.4+10-b520.11),
- IDEA 2019.3,
- Kernel: 5.3.15-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.2.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 Distro: Manjaro Linux

i tried hit Alt+Enter. IDE manual says: "Alt+Enter: Show intention actions and quick-fixes."

This is my File-Name:

```
/home/me/IdeaProjects/KeyEvent-Reader-Demo/src/Test.kt
```

Same Error i found here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-unresolved-reference-java/6734

Comment: Do you have JDK configured for project/module in "Project Structure"?

Comment: hmm. i see no misconfiguration here: 
https://imgur.com/JJ3be9q.png , https://imgur.com/SNJ4yuJ.png

Comment: and in https://imgur.com/yvth5Ik.png i dont see misconfiguration

Comment: Looks like classpath for JDK 11 is empty. Please try to recreate JDK item in IDE.

Comment: yes it tells: `undefined path variables: scope is undefined. Fix it. CLASS` https://imgur.com/ChoIuqg.png

Comment: Does it help to remove this variable?

Comment: @y.bedrov it solves the problem :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, the @y.bedrov's suggestion helps me.

The issue is that the `Classpath` is empty (under `Project Structure` -> `Platform Settings` -> `SDKs` -> `<choose active SDK>` -> `Classpath`)

To fix this, you can recreate the SDK:

1. `Project Structure` -> `Platform SDKs` -> `<choose active SDK>` -> `"-"`
2. `Project Structure` -> `Platform SDKs` -> `"+"` -> `<choose target SDK location>`

Comment: This suprisingly worked. FYI, I did this with a JDK11 openjdk build on windows.

Answer (score 2):

This was definitely some IntelliJ peoblem for me. I could solve the issue by stupidly deleting the "problematic" class and creating it again:

- Delete class and imports that refer to it in project
- Create the same class and adding imports

What generally people also suggest when having similar problem (but didn't help in my case):

- Restart IDE (File -> Invalidate caches... )
- Check Platform SDKs as mentioned in another answer here
- IntelliJ -> PReferances -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Make sure that `Kotlin Compiler` and `Java Compiler` match in versions.